# GA4 event Validation only returns 204

Tags: google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

[GA4 documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/validating-events?client_type=gtag) provides an example of how to send requests to the GA4 Measurement Protocol endpoint for validation.

Using the example providing the ids being asked for the response is always a 204 without a body when the documentation reads that there should be a response body with an array called *validationMessages*.

Does anyone know why the debug endpoint would only ever return a 204?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems a 204 status code is to be expected from GA4, i.e. no content should be returned.

From inspecting the response given in the Event Builder (https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/event-builder/) through the Network log in my browser, there is indeed a JSON response including the key `validationMessages`. I investigated and found the target URL in the Event Builder is actually `https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/mp/collect`. By sending your data to this URL, you will also receive a 200 HTTP status code and a JSON response with additional information about your request and any potential errors.

*TLDR;
You should normally receive a 204 HTTP status code, but with the debug endpoint, you will receive a 200 HTTP status code.*

Comment: Great. Thank you! That (`/debug/`) allowed me to see the following error regarding the event name ... `Only alphanumeric characters and underscores are allowed`